# Using wireless mouse A4tech G7-540 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, mouse

I am intending to get wireless mouse (most probably A4Tech G7-540) and on other 2.4G wireless mouse, but I am not sure that whether Ubuntu 10.04 LTS will support it as a plug n play, or do I need to install its drivers? As I haven't found any Linux drivers for it on A4Tech website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is plug-and-play.

However, you will not have access to the A4Tech special functions offered for Windows, as A4Tech Office Shuttle software suite works only in Windows.

I believe you can configure the programmable keys manually in Linux using the hotkey configuration tools.

I am currently using A4Tech G9 - 557 HX mouse in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin and all the base functions of the mouse are accessible, including variable resolution, mouse click, scroll and auto-configuration. I have not programmed the shuttle key yet, it pastes a website address.

Answer (score 1):

A4Tech G9 Mouse acts like two USB devices are connected. One is the mouse and the other one is the keyboard. For more information open the terminal and run: `egrep "Name|Handlers" /proc/bus/input/devices`

For all buttons and scroll it works like a mouse...

But when you click the Hot Key, the mouse acts like a keyboard.

Here is what it does:

1. It checks something (I don't know how, HID does not have too many things to check, maybe by using KeymapNotify Event)
2. Then it sends keyboard instruction - super_L + r (win + r) - <kbd>Enter</kbd> - www.win2.cn/g9 - <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Using `xev` to display contents of X events in the terminal I have found so far.

Maybe, that the button try to run a pop-up application, and the mouse sends a keyboard [1-9] set for the gesture.